# How to build chart in highchart.js where xAxis(miliseconds) and yAxis(days)?

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with build chart in highchart.js.
I need a BarChart and I have array with milliseconds. 
How I need to tune my yAxis that it show me data in format (MM:SS)?

I readed `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463287/timeline-yaxis-format-with-minutesseconds-only` but it didn't resolve my issue.

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/abruilo/uoqwm9cn/
Please note on yAxis data. How I can change it?

Thanks.

Comment: See the solutions on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463287/timeline-yaxis-format-with-minutesseconds-only.

Comment: @wergeld, I saw this. But it didn't help me. http://jsfiddle.net/abruilo/uoqwm9cn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `labels.formatter` and return date in [Highcharts.dateFormat()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat).

```
yAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels:{
    formatter:function(){
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M',this.value);
    }
  }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrstm7ga/

Comment: Replace %H:%M with %M:%S

Comment: When I replaced it I got yAxix with only (00:00).

Comment: Because ticks are in equal hours / minutes, so should be in place where columns end?